# How to recover a StackExchange Account if you only know the username, not the email adress anymore?

Tags: support, user-accounts, email, multiple-accounts, account-recovery

I once registered an account here at StackExchange, but only remember the username. How could I recover the email that belongs to that account, I tried several emails I have. None seem to work. Any chance?

Comment: Can't see any way such thing is possible. You must somehow prove you are the same person - if such thing was possible, anyone could claim he's anyone else.

Comment: that's true but at other platforms i could prove that i'm the one by loging in with username and my password, i don't have to know the email adress. thought this might be possible here too.

Comment: @Ian Is your problem on StackOverflow/Meta StackOverflow or another StackExchange site?

Comment: You can send an email to Stack Exchange, but being able to access the email associated to that account is probably required. If there are too many accounts with the same username, I don't think Stack Exchange account is going to hunt for the ones you are referring, though. Consider that, if you didn't use the account from enough time, it is probable it has been deleted.

Comment: @Alenanno I asked 3 questions on StackOverflow, about a year ago.

Comment: In Stack Exchange sites, email **is** the user name as the display names are not unique.

Comment: usernames are not in any way unique on our network, so that's not a good way to identify a lost account.. unless you happened to pick a rather unique name that nobody else has, like, say, "Ian" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could email team@stackoverflow.com with the user account you believe is yours. Telling you the email address is unacceptable, but they could likely send that account an email which you would receive (if the account is yours).

Another possibility is that if the account has a [gravatar](http://gravatar.com), you might remember which email address you signed up to gravatar with.

Comment: Just wanted to notice, that for reasons unknown they don't do it.